# python sqlite alter table failed without commit

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm learning Python with realypython Book2 now (Flask).

I encountered a bug preventing me from running a database migration using db_migrate.py. It said there is no table "tasks".

I added "connection.commit()" into the code and then it runs okay. Why do I need to force the table change using "commit()"?

Thanks.

https://github.com/realpython/book2-exercises/edit/master/flasktaskr-02/project

```
# project/db_migrate.py


from views import db
from _config import DATABASE_PATH

import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime

with sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_PATH) as connection:

    # get a cursor object used to execute SQL commands
    c = connection.cursor()

    # temporarily change the name of tasks table
    c.execute("""ALTER TABLE tasks RENAME TO old_tasks""")
    connection.commit()
    # recreate a new tasks table with updated schema
    db.create_all()

    # retrieve data from old_tasks table
    c.execute("""SELECT name, due_date, priority,
                status FROM old_tasks ORDER BY task_id ASC""")

    # save all rows as a list of tuples; set posted_date to now and user_id to 1
    data = [(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3],
            datetime.now(), 1) for row in c.fetchall()]

    # insert data to tasks table
    c.executemany("""INSERT INTO tasks (name, due_date, priority, status,
                    posted_date, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)""", data)

    # delete old_tasks table
    c.execute("DROP TABLE old_tasks")
```

Comment: If you add `connection.commit()` at the end of your snippet does it also work?  I think you are committing in the wrong place.

Comment: maybe, my guess was that the old table "tasks" needs to be renamed before db.create_all() can function (that's using SQLAlchemy) so I just force it and it seems to work.

Comment: If I moved connection.commit() to the bottom, the error message will come back.   File "/Users/apple/Github/learningtasks/db_migrate.py", line 17, in <module>
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', data)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: tasks

Comment: From what I have read, you should not have to commit the transaction for this to work.  Maybe Python's SQLite wrapper is the cause of this.

Comment: Tim, you are right. I went back and checked the code and realised that there was a typo: in this line, I put URL incorrectly instead of URI. Now it works normally.          app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, TEST_DB)